# Does this cadence have a name?

Tags: theory, analysis, cadence

The cadence on the fermata in this (simplified) example sounds familiar to me (in blue):

[image]

Since it does, I suppose it possibly has a name.

My best guesses trying to analyze it so far are:

- half cadence to the subdominant,
- a deceptive cadence to the dominant 7 on the root A. With C# being outside the key of A minor, I'm not sure it can qualify as a deceptive cadence.

I'm not sure if any of these is valid, and it doesn't give me a potential name.

Comment: For what it is worth that notation is incorrect. The extract ends on the A 6/5 chord not the root position.

Comment: The Picardie third may come into play, although it usually finishes a piece - this looks like it continues. Going from a V to a I makes it basically a perfect cadence, but the dominant part throws that into touch.

Comment: @Tim: the seventh does nullify the perfect cadence hypothesis, and so does the inversion (which erroneously doesn't show in the chord notation, as NeilMeyer pointed out). The piece continues with a repeat of measures 3 and 4, and ends in a perfect cadence. But I wrote that.

Comment: @NeilMeyer - "A6/5" - ????? (I've been ALWAYS writing it as **A7/C#**)

Comment: @MaikaSakuranomiya If you're unfamiliar with that notation and want to learn, Neil is using what we call "figured bass."

Answer (score 2):

To me it seems like a [half cadence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cadence_(music)#Half_cadence). *A7* appears before as well as the V of Dm. So my guess is that *A7* here doesn't work as a tonic, but as a dominant (of some kind).

> **Half cadence** (imperfect cadence or semicadence): any cadence ending on V, whether preceded by V of V, ii, vi, IV, or I—or any other chord. Because it sounds incomplete or suspended, the half cadence is considered a weak cadence that calls for continuation.

This also could be some combination of a modulation with a [picardy third](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picardy_third).

> It refers to the use of a major chord of the tonic at the end of a musical section that is either modal or in a minor key.

Answer (score 1):

I'd call it a Picardie cadence as the only thing you are changing is you are raising the third of the tonic chord and you are coming directly from the dominant. [The Wiki example for this cadence is almost the same](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picardy_third):

> For example, instead of a cadence ending on an A minor chord
>   containing the notes A, C, and E, a tierce de Picardie ending would
>   consist of an A major chord containing the notes A, C♯, and E. Note
>   that the minor third between the A and C of the A minor chord has
>   become a major third in the tierce de Picardie chord.

A more in-depth look would be it functions as part of a codetta where the first cadence is not quite perfect due to ending on a dominant chord and kind of a "false ending" and the last cadence is the perfect cadence you were expecting the first time.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is a pure picardy third, because it is a dominant chord. Do picardy thirds appear in dominant chords?

Comment: If you're building a seventh chord in A minor on the tonic, you would have A, C, E, and G. Change the C to a C# makes an A7.

Comment: But is picardy third used this way?

Comment: Aren't Picardie cadences supposed to end a piece? Are they still Picardie cadences with the third as the bass?

Comment: @Gauthier they are also used to end a section, not necessarily the piece.

Comment: @Shevliaskovic it wouldn't be too big of a jump especially when taking modern music into account. How many jazz or blues songs end on a dominant tonic? It could set up a phrase modulation, but there is no definite modulation in this section especially with the previous chord being the V7 of the key.

Comment: @Dom you have a point here; I (mistakenly) assumed it was a common practice period piece, but without any clarification I could be mistaken

Comment: @Shevliaskovic: I wrote the arrangement, and this ending is mine. Measures 3 and 4 are not present in the original composition, measures 1, 2, 5, 6 have the same melody and harmony as the original (which is written for male choir). Common practice was my ambition, but I am not sure the original piece and its harmony make it possible, especially the B7-5 and following tristan chord.

Comment: It might not sound jazzy/bluesy, but the harmony does make sense in those fields.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like that G that the notation considers a seventh could easily just be an chromatic passing note and that the cadence is actually just a regular V - I perfect cadence.

Comment: I doubt that; it's clearly a dominant chord. A *V* of some kind, not a *I*

Comment: I think you are mistaken as to what I mean I'm referring to the G natural that moves a semitone down from the G#  in the last chord of the piece (The A chord.)

Comment: Yes, I got that. The A->G#->G, right? If that went to A after G,  Iwould agree that it's just a passing note

Comment: @Shevliaskovic - of course it's a dominant chord, however, since the key is C/Am, from the key sig., it won't be called a V, as it's a I, as in an 'A'.

Comment: @Tim - In the second bar, the A7 is the V of Dm, right? My guess is that something similar is going on with the last A7 of the section as well.